# Using SQL Query - How to insert a row in a table with some new values and some values from another table

Tags: sql, row, oracle-sqldeveloper, multiple-columns, sql-insert

Example I have Table1 with 3 columns as col1, col2, col3. I have Table2 with 2 columns as id, col4.

**Table1**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | abc | 12 |
| qwe | rty | 34 |

**Table2**

| id | col4 |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | asdf |
| 15 | oldvalue |
| 15 | oldvalue |

I have to insert a row in Table1 such that -

1. Insert 'newvalue1' in col1, 'newvalue2' in col2.
2. In col3, insert value of id column from Table2 where col4 = 'oldvalue'.

My new row in table will be inserted and my output is -

**Output-Table1**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | abc | 12 |
| qwe | rty | 34 |
| `newvalue1` | `newvalue2` | `15` |

Which the SQL query can achieve the above output?

I am using Oracle SQL developer.

INSERT INTO Table1(col1, col2, col3)
values
('newvalue1', 'newvalue2', Select distinct id from Table2 where col4 = 'oldvalue');

getting error -> ORA-00936: missing expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, to insert into table baaed on some query result, you can use [insert into table... select...from...](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php) statement, and the subquery should contains all the columns.

Here is the [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/0coCzgzE):

```
insert into table1(col1,col2,col3)
    Select distinct 'newvalue1', 'newvalue2', id 
    from Table2 
    where col4 = 'oldvalue'
```

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | abc | 13 |
| qwe | rty | 34 |
| newvalue1 | newvalue2 | 15 |